# Using Midvatten plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, midvatten

After installation of the Midvatten plug in (QGIS 2.12 Lyon), I tried to get confidence with the plugin following the tutorial. When trying to plot stratigraphy data, a QGIS error shows up: "the stratigraphy plot failed, check Midvatten settings and your data". I'm going to link an image of the error[image: error using Midvatten plug in]

Is there anyone having some experience with this plug in?

Answer (score 3):

1) You need to first fix the settings of your database for stratigraphy

[image]

2) Select the layer obs_p_w_strat, select some observation points you want to be plotted and choose Midvatten - View plots - Plot Stratigraphy

[image]

Comment: Hello Gene, please can you explain better "fix the settings"? I just switch to the tab "Stratigraphy" and i select from the table dropdown menu "Stratigraphy", is this what you mean fix the settings?. Even doing so, i've got always the same error

Comment: In the dialog, have-you the green text with "Correct..." ?

Comment: and have_you selected some points ?

Comment: Hello Gene, Yes, the text is "correct table! all the expected columns...". I noticed something quite strange, maybe connected with my issue.When trying to select features on the left side of the screen (with the rectangular area selector), the ones on the center of the screen get selected (underlined in yellow). I'll start from scratch. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: I think you have encountered a QGIS bug, which now should be fixed:
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14327 BTW, there are more QGIS bugs introduced which causes major problems for the Midvatten plugin:
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14575 Please help reporting QGIS bugs and give feedback to developers so this plugin can still be used in future versions of QGIS. /Josef - author of Midvatten plugin